# Combining array values for the same associative key

Tags: php, arrays

I've got this array, and I want to loop through it and add up the values prices that are on the same OrderDate. The other values like the Discount code I want to add as a sub-array.

```
   array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["OrderDate"]=>
        string(10) "2018-01-01"
        ["DiscountCode"]=>
        NULL
        ["TotalRevenue"]=>
        string(9) "147618.76"
        ["Discount_Revenue"]=>
        string(8) "13453.77"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        ["OrderDate"]=>
        string(10) "2018-01-01"
        ["DiscountCode"]=>
        string(6) "SALE38"
        ["TotalRevenue"]=>
        string(8) "364.92"
        ["Discount_Revenue"]=>
        string(8) "4083.64"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(4) {
        ["OrderDate"]=>
        string(10) "2018-01-01"
        ["DiscountCode"]=>
        string(9) "WELCOME20"
        ["TotalRevenue"]=>
        string(6) "113.83"
        ["Discount_Revenue"]=>
        string(6) "113.83"
      }
    }
```

So it should then look like:

```
 array(3) {
          [0]=>
          array(4) {
            ["OrderDate"]=>
            string(10) "2018-01-01"
            ["DiscountCodes"]=> array {
            [0] => "DISCOUNT"
            [1] => "SALE38"
            [2] => "WELCOME20"
             )
            ["TotalRevenue"]=>
            string(9) "147618.76"
            ["Discount_Revenue"]=>
            string(8) "13453.77"
          }
        }
```

I believe I have fixed it using this loop adding to the array if the key exists. Not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it though?

```
    foreach ($results as $k => $result){

        if( array_key_exists($result['OrderDate'], $arr)){

            $arr[$result['OrderDate']]['price'] += $result['TotalRevenue'];
            $arr[$result['OrderDate']]['new'] =  false;


        } else {
            $arr[$result['OrderDate']] = array(
                'price' => $result['TotalRevenue'],
                'new' => true
            );
        }


    }
```

Comment: share what have tried

Comment: I've added what I have tried, plus I have tried array_reduce but that went more wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to my own solution if anyone else needs it.

```
    $arr = array();

    foreach ($results as $k => $result){

        if( array_key_exists($result['OrderDate'], $arr)){

            $arr[$result['OrderDate']]['Total_Revenue'] += $result['TotalRevenue'];
            $arr[$result['OrderDate']]['Discount_Revenue'] += $result['Discount_Revenue'];
            isset($result['DiscountCode']) ? $arr[$result['OrderDate']]['Discount_Code'][] = $result['DiscountCode'] : '';
            $arr[$result['OrderDate']]['new'] =  false;


        } else {
            $arr[$result['OrderDate']] = array(
                'Total_Revenue' => $result['TotalRevenue'],
                'Discount_Revenue' => $result['Discount_Revenue'],
                'new' => true
            );
            isset($result['DiscountCode']) ? $arr[$result['OrderDate']]['Discount_Code'][] = $result['DiscountCode'] : '';
        }


    }
```